# Parameters in DynamicJasper AutoText fields?

Tags: java, dynamic-jasper

Given a report with a parameter, say `foo` with value `bar`, I'd expect the following to either print `bar` if it supported parameters, or `$P{foo}` if it only supported static text.

```
    AutoText showBatchAutoText = new AutoText("$P{foo}",
                                 AutoText.POSITION_HEADER,
                                 HorizontalBandAlignment.CENTER);
```

Instead it prints `((java.lang.String)parameter_foo.getValue())`, implying it does some kind of logic on the field...

Is it supposed to work? Am I misusing the "message" type AutoText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamicJasper wraps the string in quotes before sending it to Jasper. So, *sql injection attack* style, you can bypass it with escaped quotes.

```
AutoText showBatchAutoText = new AutoText("\" + $P{foo} + \"",
                             AutoText.POSITION_HEADER,
                             HorizontalBandAlignment.CENTER);
```

A hack, but... it does the trick.